# JS/JSF Session timeout information display

Tags: javascript, jsf, session, logout

I'm using JSF 1.2 with JBoss 4.2 and Richfaces 3.3.
For my current application I have to build a small panel which always displays a progressbar
and the time in minutes till the session will suspend (user get logged out). 
Well, till now all is working fine. I implemented my solution via javascript and that works flawless.

But now I have a big problem with ajax requests. I see currently no solution to get a handler or something which is fired on every ajax request (to reset my progressbar and the minutes till logout).

Here is my code so far:

```
var timeLeft = document.getElementById('valueObject').value;
var maxTimeoutTime = document.getElementById('valueObject').value;
var intervalID;
function updateProgress() {
var percentageValue = timeLeft / (maxTimeoutTime / 100);
$('form:sessionTimeoutBar').component.setValue(percentageValue);
timeLeft = timeLeft - 1000;
if (timeLeft <= 0){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
 }
}

function resetProgress() {
alert("CALLED");
timeLeft = document.getElementById('valueObject').value;
$('form:sessionTimeoutBar').component.setValue(100);
clearInterval(intervalID);
intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);
} 

function startProgress() {
$('form:sessionTimeoutBar').component.enable();
$('form:sessionTimeoutBar').component.setValue(100);
intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 1000);
}
```

`timeLeft` and `maxTimeoutTime` are retreived over an hidden input field which gets the information from a managed bean method. 
`startProgress()` is called via onload by the body tag.

Comment: @Anish: please don't format non-code as code. "JSF", "RichFaces", "ajax", etc are framework/library/technolocy names, not code!

Comment: I think I found a solution. Richfaces has a nice ajax component called "a4j:queue" which queues all ajax events. After placing this component on my application and adding the js event oncomplete I can easily execute a method on every ajax call. Thank you all!